# How can I get the data of a clicked marker inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a Google Maps plugin for Wordpress.

Visit: http://andresposadallano.com/sym/tiendas

I have the the following php loop to show the data markers.

```
// Start the Loop
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    $query->the_post();                                  
    $id = get_the_id();
    $latitud = get_post_meta($id, 'latitud')[0];
    $longitud = get_post_meta($id, 'longitud')[0]; 
?>

<li>
    <a href="" class="point" onclick="show_info(); click_to_move(); return false;" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-content="<?php the_content(); ?>" data-latitud="<?php echo $latitud ?>" data-longitud="<?php echo $longitud ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> 
</li> 

<?php endwhile;
```

Then, I have the following function to get the point title, only for the clicked point.

```
function show_info(){
     jQuery('#nav-acc a.point').each(function(index){
           var tit_t = jQuery(this).data('title');
           console.log( index + ': ' + tit_t );
     });
}
```

**Here is showing me all the titles in the list, how can I print only the title of the clicked marker?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.each` loop. Send element from `click` event and use it. Something like this.

```
<a href="" class="point" onclick="show_info(this); click_to_move(); return false;"... 
//....                                      ^^^^
function show_info(elem){
           var tit_t = $(elem).data('title');
           console.log( index + ': ' + tit_t );
}
```

Comment: Uhhh. Thank you Alex :)  You saved my life. 
Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Sure. Thank you!!